# option tag returning string value instead of number for ngModel in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

HTML:

```
<select [(ngModel)]='i.PaycodeId'>
  <option *ngFor="let j of payCode" [value]='j.ID'>{{j.value}}</option>
</select>
```

payCode:

```
[{"ID":0,"value":"Cycle"},{"ID":1,"value":"Truck"},{"ID":2,"value":"Car"}]
```

In `i.PaycodeId`, through `ngModel`, it is setting numbers as string value not numbers like `"1"/"2"` while the value passed to select is object having ID's value as number.
I want this value as **number** only.

Comment: what is the type of `i.PaycodeId` in the class?

Comment: So sorry for it. `<tr *ngFor='let i of bonusArray'>` where bonusArray is an array or object which contains a number type value 'Paycode'. I am creating a table with the help of bonusArray array and drop down is one of it's column item. Now I contains an object with one of its property 'PaycodeId' and type of it is number. But when I select something from dropdown it returns my string instead of number as you can see it in my original post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Please check out [Asaf Hananel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47120438/1961059) below - it's what you're probably looking for.**

---

You could separate the binding out like this:

```html
<select [ngModel]="i.PaycodeId" (ngModelChange)="onChangeSelection($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let j of payCode" [value]='j.ID'>{{j.value}}</option>
</select>
```

And in your Component:

```js
onChangeSelection(selected) {
    this.i.PaycodeId = parseInt(selected);
}
```

---

> Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AHtCmp7ntmLcnqlA4Eqb?p=preview) for example usage

Comment: I could have done this before but I was just wondering if there is any straight forward simple way. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: it's not logical angular team should fix this, there the option must take the value even if its type is number

Answer (score 55):

Instead of using [value], use [ngValue].

```
<select [(ngModel)]='i.PaycodeId'>
  <option *ngFor="let j of payCode" [ngValue]='j.ID'>{{j.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't know why this is not marked as the correct answer, solves the problems of parsing the value on the modelChange event.

Comment: ngValue is working, should mark this corrent answer

Comment: This works for me using reactive forms..  so no need for onChange tweak! Upvoted.

Comment: In my case it did not help. Don't have idea why.

Comment: Really good, , should mark this as correct answer!

Comment: As some people said, this should be marked as the correct answer, this is the right way to solve the issue and the current accepted answer is more like a workaround

Comment: thanks very much, bro, was using enum in options and couldn't find any solution, this worked like a wonder for me!!