# ngIf not triggering on update of [(ngModel)] variable

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a select with options. The select has an `[(ngModel)]` directive saving the selected values into "rightFieldTypeId." I then have elements I would like to display based on the value of "rightFieldTypeId." The string interpolation of rightFieldTypeId `{{ rightFieldTypeId }}` displays the correct value as I select different options (i.e. 1, 2 or 3). However, my elements based on the `*ngIf` directives never seem to evaluate/change.

```
<div class="d-flex w-50">
    <select class="form-control w-25 mr-4" [(ngModel)]="rightFieldTypeId">
        <option *ngFor="let option of fieldTypeOptions" [value]="option.id">
            {{ option.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
    {{ rightFieldTypeId }}
    <span *ngIf="rightFieldTypeId === 2">This is Text</span>
    <edit-spec-wizard-operations-builder *ngIf="rightFieldTypeId === 3"></edit-spec-wizard-operations-builder>
</div>
```

Any insight on how to achieve displaying different elements using the `*ngIf` directive based on the current value coming out of the `[(ngModel)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML `option` value is a `string` and comparing with strict comparison (`===`) will not not coerce types, so `2 === '2'` will be `false`.

So couple ways to go with it:

1. Use double equal comparison - `==`;
2. Use `+` to make an integer from a string `*ngIf="+rightFieldTypeId === 2"`, but with this you could get a runtime error if `rightFieldTypeId` can't be coerced to an integer;
3. Simply compare to a string, because `rightFieldTypeId` will always be a string `*ngIf="rightFieldTypeId === '2'"`

Comment: Yes, changing to compare to string `=== '2'` did the trick. Was a bit confused since I've hard typed both `option.id` and `rightFieldTypeId` to be number in typescript. Good tidbit to know, thanks.

Comment: For anyone in the future, I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921596/option-tag-returning-string-value-instead-of-number-for-ngmodel-in-angular

which suggests changing the [value] directive on the <options> tag to [ngValue] to emit the proper data type instead of finding work arounds if you require a non-string type to be emitted